# I can't get the variables from the bundles before an iterator in make.com

Tags: arrays, json, make.com, integromat-apps

I'm working with a webhook that sends me 3 arrays of data, I've tried a lot of things to save each variable and use them for a database.
[Bundles seems ok, those are the variables that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9xYN.jpg)

The iterator shows me correctly all the variables, but I don't know how to extract them and use it in the next step, as you see in the image the bundle seems ok, but then the data doesn't split correctly.

[all the variables don't apear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkIFT.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.